# Data type for storing hour interval

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a specific data type that allows you to store data for which hour interval an event has occurred (for example "15.00-15.59", "16.00-16.59" etc)?

If there isn't, what is the best way to store this data?

Comment: Which database?

Comment: @chickenchilli  
If you have a database for sales, and want to analyze sales made between 12.00 and 13.00 for example

Comment: Many databases support `interval` data types.  It depends on the database.

Comment: chickenchilli means which database product....Sql Server, Oracle, MySql...?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I'm using Mysql. So a date-time interval data type could store an interval in this format hh:mm-hh:mm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html

So you would need two fields.. time_start and time_end to reflect your case.

Answer (score 0):

Postgre SQL `Range Types` ([Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html)) fits better in your problem, because it uses a single field to save the time interval.

It has many operators to check overlapping and etc. In addition, using `Canonicalization Functions` you can convert -discrete data- from interval (range) to its *Canonical Form*.